# A weird thing about ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I plot the function f(x,y). x goes from 0 to 25 and y goes from 0 to 12.
So, my plot should look elongated since the range of x is twice as long as the range of y.

The problem is that, mathematica rescales the size of the axes, so that I see a square plot eventhough I see x->[0,25] and y->[0,12].

This is what I do:

ListPlot3D[Abs[list], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 AxesLabel -> {xx, yy, f(xx,yy)}, PlotRange -> All]

Does anybody know how could I see an elongated plot?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `BoxRatios -> Automatic`

```
ListPlot3D[Abs[list], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 AxesLabel -> {"xx", "yy", "f(xx,yy)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Yes! That works! Thanks @E.O.! And know I want to do the opposite thing with f(x,y), because the variation of f versus x and y is supersmall, and I woukd like to appreciate the shapes of my surface. So how can I exagerate the f(x,y) axes keeping the (x,y) grid elongated??

Comment: Try adjusting it manually by changing the values in `BoxRatios->{1,2,3}`

Comment: Perfect!! It works!! Thanks, I appreciate it E.O.!!